# Javascript - Timeslots handling by removing service duration

Tags: javascript, arrays, appointment, timeslots

I am new to this forum, and I came here because my brains are exploding but I really would like to achieve building an booking system application. The Following is my story:

I am working with the following data:

- An Array with timeslots which have 5 minutes in between them, so that the user can select a timeslot to book his appointment. It looks like below:

`var timeslotArray = ["09:00", "09:05", "09:10", "09:15", "09:20", "09:25" ... ,"18:00"]`

***NOTE:*** I removed from the "timeslotArray" already some times, for example like a break from "12:00" till "13:00". Or if there are other appointments, then I managed to remove those times. So I end up with a "timeslotArray" which looks like:

`var timeslotArray = ["09:00", "09:05", "09:25" ... ,"18:00"]`

Next there are services which can be booked, and these services have durations. Let's say the user selected a service with a duration of 10 minutes. Now my big question is how can I remove the duration of the service from the "timeslotArray" so that the user only can select the available timeslots. Because now there is a break from 09:10 till 09:25. This means that 09:05 should not be visible in the "timeslotArray" because the service duration is 10 minutes.(begin break is 09:10, minus 10 minutes is 09:00). Also keep in mind that there are next to the breaks also other appointments which I need to remove 10 min from the starting time.

I am working fully in Javascript and have tried a lot, but there was always at least one scenario which I had not covered during the coding.

I hope there is someone who can help me even if it is a small step. Thanks anyway!

Kind regards,

Hanake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how you doing?

Check this code:

```js
var timeslotArray = ["09:00", "09:05", "09:10", "09:15", "09:20", "09:25","18:00"]

function updateArray(timeChosen,duration){
var startTime = new Date(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+timeChosen));
var endTime =  new Date(startTime.getTime() + duration * 60000);

timeslotArray.forEach((hour, index)=>{
var hourAsDate = new Date(Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+ hour));
if (hourAsDate < endTime && hourAsDate >= startTime){
timeslotArray[index] = null; 
}
});
timeslotArray = timeslotArray.filter((hour) => {return hour != null;});
}

updateArray("09:00",20);
console.log(timeslotArray);
```

the function `updateArray` should get a string of an hour (eg. "05:00" or "09:00") and a number for duration (which indicate minutes).

The array are going through a `forEach` command that makes all the hours between the start time and the end time `null`, and afterwards filter all the nulls out (I did that so because removing parts of an array inside a loop causes indexing troubles)

Have fun hacking!